# Show table cell details when cell is clicked in modal or as popoup or alert dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed Table with One row with title of month and cell that has inner table with separate rows and cell.I would like to show the content of any cell form innertable details when row of parent table is clicked.

For example, If any user click January, then it would show the details of events of Month of January as alert Dialog box/popup or alert Dialog box which can be later cancelled with close button.

Here is my table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Events</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Events</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>This is information I want to show as modal when this January cell is clicked</td>
  </tr>

</table>

    </td>
 
  </tr>




  <tr>
    <td>February

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Events</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>This is information I want to show as modal when this Feburary cell is clicked</td>
  </tr>

</table>

    </td>
 
  </tr>

</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible. Thanks for your any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you asking?

Also I see that you're not correctly using the `tr` and `td`s as expected you have to make each row for ex. `january`, `feb` etc... and not to create a table inside `td`, since the the below code checks on row as you requested the other contents too are in the row, which may alert again with only those child values.

What I am trying to say is try to order the data in row and data wise.

```js
$("table tr").click(function() {
  alert($(this).children("td").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Events</h1>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Events</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>This is information I want to show as modal when this January cell is clicked</td>
          </tr>

        </table>

      </td>

    </tr>




    <tr>
      <td>February

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Events</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>This is information I want to show as modal when this Feburary cell is clicked</td>
          </tr>

        </table>

      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

here is the sample example what you can achieve or you can further explore more options:

```js
$(".MainTable tr").click(function() {
  alert($(this).children("td").text());
});
```

```css
.MainTable,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
}

.row td {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <h1>Events</h1>

  <table class="MainTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>

    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
      <td>January
      </td>
      <td>Events</td>
      <td>
        This is information I want to show as modal when this January cell is clicked
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
      <td>
        February
      </td>
      <td>Events</td>
      <td>
        This is information I want to show as modal when this February cell is clicked
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: This is great. The first option works for me..but nontheless I will explore with second suggestion too. just for change I did change table to table table tr as I was targeting for second table. How can I target the nth child just in css we do td:nth-child(), I was expecting to show details of 2nd cell but other should remain static. For now it shows alert in both events cell and details cell which I only want to restrict on details cell only.

Comment: Glad that it helped! you should always have selector class if you  have multiple tables which will help you to get what exactly you need, coming to the nth-child() you have `n` number of articles available to fetch, logic goes same as I mentioned above so don't worry about that, just keep exploring things! cheers. for table to table tr instead of using like that use a selector class as I did in the code(MainTable) etc.